# How to create extended splash screen in MVVM pattern in Windows store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, splash-screen

I am not using any MVVM framework, but I was just practicing MVVM, so I thought how can I implement extended splash screen in MVVM pattern. I have seen the [extended splash screen sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-screen-sample-89c1dc78) from MSDN. Any ideas how to implement it in MVVM ?

Comment: Why would you need to implement a splash screen with MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You would implement it the same way as you do the other pages in your application which depends on your preferences or framework used for MVVM. There is no real difference unless you are facing some specific problem.

Comment: If I use extended splash screen my OnNavigatedTo event will have `SplashScreen` object as parameter. So how can I handle OnNavigatedTo event in ViewModel ? How can I get `NavigationEventArgs` parameter in ViewModel ? If you can answer specifically for MVVM Light then it will be great otherwise generic answer is also accpeted.